# How to determine the correlation using $X^2$ values

Tags: data-mining

I am trying to understand how to calculate the correlation between two variables using p values. I am familiar with using the classic $X^2$ formula from the The Morgan Kaufmann series in data mining. The formula described in the text uses the expected frequency and observed frequency. To calculate the $X^2$ value. Then the $X^2$ value is compared with the significance level to determine if the variables are correlated. However, this example uses p-values.

[image]

The table above shows the contingency table for a set of values and the table below shows the p-values

[image]

How can I determine if the two variables are correlated? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful calculator for solving this problem. https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/default2.aspx